# Does MySql also need to be installed on computers that access the database?

Tags: mysql, database

I am making a GUI and using MySql, if I send the executable to another computer will the computer on which the app is executed also require MySql or is it just required to be connected to the internet?

Comment: Im sorry, this may be a stupid question but I just want to confirm before I spend a long time learning this.

Comment: do you have a webapp? a desktop app? it really depends on your need, you can have an app that connects to an online DB or you can have an app that creates it's own DB locally (i would use sqlite for that instead of mysql) if you have a webapp i'm not sure what you mean by "executable"

Comment: It is a desktop app but I am making it with a database so that when I modify some data in the future I do not have to resend the data to all users again as it will update all the exe files through the database. I have set up something with MySql but am having problems with remote connection, looking for a simpler alternative if there is any.

Comment: will the app make an extensive use of the database? is that only config or data? it REAAAAAALLY depends on your need, you could have the app do an http request to some site and return the needed data but if the app make strong use of the database you must use mysql and bundle a lightweight client in your app

Comment: The app relies entirely on the database, it is basically 3 combo box's and a text box for which all data is obtained from the database. Could I possibly run this without MySql? because I dont think its worth purchasing a full server just for this single app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second option is right theres only a need of internet connection.
You see in your code for example in java you defined IP adress(in other worlds path) to database server(e.g 110.0.2.1 or even localhost).
When other computer takes your executable it only tries to connect to database server and sends whatever you programmed on it(request) in the form of SQL Query and waits for a response.
Other computers with your executables do not process queries just seds requests and recieve replies therefore they do not need to have installed mysql

Comment: Thank you that clears a lot up for me. Does the executable not access the data in the tables directly? Does it do it all through the Sql code in the query?

Comment: To explain it exactly you need to understand difference between SQL and MySQL. SQL is a languqge designed to work with databases.MySQL is a system that runs a database and processes queries. MySql only undrestands SQL and do all "dirty work"  for you. So thats a answer for both your questions. Every computer can use SQL to ask for whatever it wants from database server. Database server (with installed MySQL) takes that processes it and sends the result back to you.

Answer (score 1):

You need a server and a client to communicate. Kind of like you need a mouth and an ear to make a conversation.
For example, browsing a website takes a web server and a web browser.

It's essentially the same with MySQL - you need a server and a client. They both can come in the same installation package, so you may be under the impression it takes the same thing on both ends, but in fact you'll be running something else on your server and something else on your client machine.

Now, depending on your application, you may or you may not to install a MySQL client on the client machines. You can have a built-in client in your application, or your application can assume there is a client library on the machine, in which you case you will need to install it separately or have your application's installer do it on top of installing your application.

## TL;DR

You may need to install a MySQL client on your client machine unless your application has a built-in client.